# nHibernate w/ASP.NET Session Per Request And Active Work Item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am building an ASP.NET application using nhibernate and I implemented the session per request architecture. Each request I am opening a session, using it, then closing it. I am using one large object across several views and I am storing the object in user session cache so it maintains state for them across several different pages. The users do not want to have to save their changes on each page, they want the ability to navigate between several pages making changes, then commit them to the DB. This works well except for when the users try to hit a page that triggers lazy loading on the proxy object (which fails due to the session per request design closing the nhibernate session in the previous request). I know that turning lazy loading off would fix it; however, that is not an option due to the performance issues it would cause in other areas. I have tried changing the session per request design but have had no luck since I do not know when it is "safe" to close the nhibernate session.

Has anyone else done anything similar to this or have any advice?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Keeping any objects in user session - the server session, server resource is not the best approach. Just imagine, that accidently your application will be very very successful... and there will be many users... therefore many sessions == many resources.

I would suggest *(based on some experience)*, try to re-think the architecture to avoid session. Extreme would be to go to single page application... but even some async during "...navigation among several pages..." will be better.

All that will mean, that:

- we passs data to client (standard ASP.NET MVC way with rendered views or some Web Api JSON)
- if needed we send data back to server (binding of forms or formatting JSON)

In these scenarios, standard NHiberante session will work. Why? Because we "reload and reassign" objects with standard NHibernat infrastructure. That would be the way I suggest to go...

But if you want to follow your way, then definitely check the merge functionality of NHibernate:

- [9.4.2. Updating detached objects](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-updating-detached)
- [9.4.3. Reattaching detached objects](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-update-lock)
- [19.1.4. Initializing collections and proxies](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-fetching-initialization)

Some cites:

> In an application with a separate business tier, the business logic must "prepare" all collections that will be needed by the web tier before returning. This means that the business tier should load all the data and return all the data already initialized to the presentation/web tier that is required for a particular use case. Usually, the application calls `NHibernateUtil.Initialize()` for each collection that will be needed in the web tier (this call must occur before the session is closed) or retrieves the collection eagerly using a NHibernate query with a FETCH clause or a FetchMode.Join in ICriteria. This is usually easier if you adopt the Command pattern instead of a Session Facade.
>
> **You may also attach a previously loaded object to a new ISession with `Merge()`** or `Lock()` before accessing uninitialized collections (or other proxies). No, NHibernate does not, and certainly should not do this automatically, since it would introduce ad hoc transaction semantics!